# Automatically disappearing pop-over messages in Appian?

Tags: user-interface, notifications, popover, appian

I am struggeling to find the correct search term for a temporary notification window similar to the Windows pop-up "Safe To Remove Hardware" and how to implement it in Appian once a button is clicked.

[image: Safe To Remove Hardware]

The key features of this kind of pop-over are

- The messages disappears after e.g. 10s.
- Before the 10s passed, one can click the message away by clicking on a `X` on the upper right.

I am aware of the property `confirmHeader`, `confirmMessage` (see [documentation on Submit Link](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.3/Submit_Link_Component.html)), but this pop-over does not disappear automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could you some combination of local variables along with a!refreshVariable() function but it is not possible to refresh every 10 seconds. The lowest value is 30 seconds.

refreshVariable documentation:
https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.3/fnc_evaluation_a_refreshvariable.html