# Permanent pop-over after the end of a process in Appian

Tags: user-experience, appian

To my understanding it is not possible to close an opened browser tabs programmatically in Appian (although I have not found a written confirmation anywhere in the docs). What is the best practice to deal with that issue?

An idea would be disable the tab in question by overlaying a see-through gray layer on top of the tab in question including a message "Please close this tab." similar to the [Appian maintenance message](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/22.1/Appian_Administration_Console.html#maintenance-window)
I intend to achieve that by switching on the visibility property `showWhen`of the uppermost (gray) layer once the tab is disabled. Any other thoughs maybe from an UX perspective?

PS: I will be asking in the Appian Community as well, but I prefer the wider audience of SO.

#### References

- [Automatically disappearing pop-over messages in Appian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69222661/automatically-disappearing-pop-over-messages-in-appian)
- [Appian UX Design Guide](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/22.1/ux_getting_started.html)
- [Appian Docu on Card Choices](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/22.1/card-choices-component.html) which features the property `showWhen`.

Answer (score 0):

We had very similar problem. We expected user to complete task within X minutes. We have done this by:

- starting process model that have user input node with interface.
- on this user input node we have setup time event exception.
- this time event is triggered after x+30seconds once form is started.
- line go from exception to end node.
- end node needs to terminate process
- on UI we calculate how much time past after starting form (refresh variable, refreshed every time user click)
- 2 layers on UI - one main, one once X minutes past after start

[Exceptions Tab](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/22.3/Process_Node_and_Smart_Service_Properties.html#exceptions-tab)